# Unable to show scene or sprite from spritebuilder

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, spritebuilder

I followed the quickstart tutorial and a couple others but can't find why my new image and scene can't display after the initial scene.

```
class MainScene : CCNode {
 var newMenu = CCNode()
 var newSprite = CCNode()

 override init() {
  super.init()
  newMenu = CCBReader.load("ccbResources/NewMenu")
  newSprite = CCBReader.load("ccbResources/NewSprite")
  newSprite.position = CGPoint(x: 229, y:30)
}
}
```

I created a custom class for NewMenu and NewSprite in Spritebuilder.  After publishing and running in xcode neither the menu or sprite show up. I know that newMenu is loading because I created a class NewMenu that logs a message when the ccbResource is loaded just like the tutorial said to do.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not familiar with swift, however I think this should be like this

```
newSprite = CCBReader.load("ccbResources/NewSprite.png")
```

**.png** or whatever file you load.